# What would people on multi-generational ships eat?

Tags: space-travel

Strange! this question does not seem to be on site with a search (only what to wear). I am concerned about the psychological aspect of food production and eating. Clearly tube food is out and I think production agriculture will be necessary besides molecular printers. Thoughts welcome.

Comment: Not-quite-necessary Simpsons reference: ["Soylent Green - Now With More Girls!"](https://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/File:Soylentgreen.gif)

Comment: It's the circle of poo!  In Space!  https://www.metrolyrics.com/circle-of-poo-lyrics-south-park.html

Comment: Protein bars. [Snowpiercer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowpiercer) was effectively a generation ship.

Answer (score 8):

**They would probably be vegan by necessity**

Despite a lot of the negative press that has been out there over time about the vegan diet, the one thing that everyone seems to be able to agree on is that it is less resource intensive than an omnivorous diet largely because of the amount of land, water, food et al required to raise animals to eat rather than to grow crops. Taking that to the next logical step for a generation ship, you can't grow cows hydroponically. You can grow most plants that way though.

Most of the research I have been doing on this topic of late (and it is a lot) is telling me that for physical health, a well planned and balanced vegan diet doesn't impede your health, and in many contexts actually improves it. Iron, protein and other ingredients for harnessing energy and building muscle are available in a plant based diet more readily than you might imagine, so I don't think that part of it will be an issue.

The initial suggestions seem to be the same for mental health, but there is still a lot to do in that regard. Certainly a vegan diet is better than a meat based diet for *fuelling* your brain because it can't use much more than glucose as an energy source. But, there are still some strong arguments that without planning, an omnivorous diet is better for *maintaining* the brain, due to essential fatty acids, in particular Omega 3, DHAs, Taurine, Vitamins D, B12 - the list goes on.

Some of this you can get from a well planned vegan diet, others you need supplements for, others we're still doing the research on them. Suffice to say though that if you're careful, you can not only survive on a vegan diet, you can thrive on it. What we don't know about this as a long term dietary proposition we're researching now to find out.

This is good news for your generation ship as if you have a good hydroponics bay and the right seed stocks, you can support your crew more or less indefinitely this way and it will take FAR less resources and space to do so than it would if you also added meat animals to the closed environment of your ship. If for no other reason than they are competing with you for the oxygen in the atmosphere of your ship that the plants are creating, having animals with you as a herd is a really bad idea.

I say 'more or less' because like so many things relating to biology, it's not as simple as growing the right food. There is another aspect to a generation ship that must be considered - ecological balance.

The earth is a hideously complex ecology and a generation ship basically has to replicate the vast majority of that on a smaller scale. This is a practical impossibility to begin with because many of the life forms that you bring with you, including bacteria and the like, are going to evolve while you're on the ship meaning you really can't know how your ecology will evolve with them over time. You can do your best to stabilise your closed environment of course, but limiting the variety of animals is going to make things simpler.

Arguably, you're still going to need bees for pollination, but the truth is that the fewer varieties of animals you need on the ship with you the less complex your closed ecology needs to be. Also, the less chance of diseases jumping species like SARS or Swine Flu, meaning that the environment is less likely to attack you. You're still not safe, but leaving as many animals either at home or in cold storage as you can lowers your overall risk.

There is still a lot of work to be done in figuring out what plants you can grow, how many of them you need to thrive to support your crew and what supplements you need to bring along, but I'd be starting with a vegan diet just to reduce your ecological footprint in the first instance.

Comment: Just a sidenote: if you are bothering with a generation ship, probably you are going to colonize a distant planet? Being that the case, it might make sense to transport a few species of livestock as well (assuming an artificial animal womb is not available you need to keep a living female specimen during whole journey), giving you access to some amount of meat (maybe just enough for the pregnant women and little kids, definitely not enough to have a steak ready twice a day).

Comment: Having cows is probably tricky but growing meat in a petry dish shouldn't be too hard if you have the technology to build a generaton ship. It is already possible now, it is just too expensive to be useful.

Comment: Also worth noting that the fewer species you have the more catastrophic any problems will be. If bees are your only pollinator and a bee-killing problem (say a well meant but ultimately lethal pesticide) crops up then you’re well and truly boned. But if you have bees, wasps, butterflies and a few different classes of beetle then your overall biosphere is far more robust. The same goes for plants. It doesn’t matter how easy your superpotatoes are to grow if a single strain of fungus can wipe them all out.

Comment: Also: Strictly speaking if you’re exploiting an animal to perform pollination for you it can be argued the food isn’t vegan. Bit of an extreme viewpoint there though.

Comment: @JoeBloggs It is very tricky to keep the adjective "vegan" from turning into a ideologic finger pointing device. Vegetarians are so much more friendly. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Asteroids.

I mean, you could recycle waste for food (and NASA already does for water), but what if you are finicky, like me?

Well asteroids have water, and carbon, and nitrogen.  And that's basically what a plant is made of right there (ok well not entirely, but talking in generalities).  Stop at the occasional asteroid, mine a few tons of the good stuff off there.  Process it into the proper fertilizers and dirt.  Add light with your nuclear powered grow bulbs.  Plant your wheat and tomatoes and sunflower seeds for oil (cause you need that cheap oil for vegan cheese), next thing you know you have your space pizza.  And space pizza means space pizza party.

That's how we're doing it on my Disco Generation Ship.  :)

Comment: Stopping a spaceship costs a huge amount of energy. you don't want to do that more than once. So this is a really bad idea.

Comment: That is a good point, my friend.  I see my dream of space pizza floating away in space behind the ever accelerating ship...   Oh, but what if they scoop up an asteroid mid-flight and mine it on the drive?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of this depends on your actual generation ship, most of all on your means of propulsion and on the price of getting material into orbit. The reason being that you need to build your ship in space (due to the rocket equation), and you want to build a really, really big ship. And the bigger you can build it, the more options you have for outfitting it.

But let's look at things in detail:

A generation ship by definition has to be huge. And it's purpose is to get a minimum viable population (plus some safety margin) to a distant destination.

So, we are talking about a ship that can accomodate some 5000 people. And accomodate does not only mean to safely store them away and shield them from harm (radiation being only one of the problems), but to provide enough room for them to actually live. They also need to occupy themselves. And they will want to breathe constantly...
All this means that they will be farming aboard their vessel, providing them with food, oxygen, and occupation, and quite some recycling.
So, it is safe to assume that there will be fresh vegetables.

Arriving at their destination they will want to be able to establish a colony, which means producing food. We already covered vegetables. But maybe they also want to bring animals.
Animals are a bit of a problem. You can transport frozen sperm, even frozen fertilized eggs, but you need a living womb to grow an animal from them. You won't want to transport an entire minimum viable population of cows with you, plus one for pigs, chicken, and whatever else you want to bring. But you may want to bring enough animals to make sure you have at least one living female when you arrive, to re-breed as many animals of that kind from the frozen eggs once you arrive.
That means that at any time, you will have one living female of any species, plus a few extra as a safety margin.

And that means there will be steak!!

Not on a daily basis, but from time to time there will be meat on the menu. Which is actually a good idea, because diversity helps with the morale as well as with providing energy and essentials.

But there is a huge downside, obviously (there always is, when you talk about engineering).
Those animals need space, and they need food. It is often said that for every calorie you get out of meat, you need ten calories to feed to the animals.
I mentioned that the means for building your ship is important.
Assuming you have the use of a space elevator. Then all that limits you (apart from engineering), is how much material and effort you are willing to invest in your ship. The larger you can build it, the more animals you can bring, and the more meat you can have on the table.
If you don't have a space elevator, building your ship bigger than necessary to fulfill it's primary role will be prohibitively expensive.

So, to sum it up: The population of your generation ship will mostly live on vegetables, with occasional bits of meat. And the amount of meat will depend on whether or not you have a space elevator at your starting planet.

Answer (score 3):

**They will eat genetically engineered yeast.**

[image: yeast tank]

Yeast are good food.  They are easy to grow.  One could use electricity and water to reduce CO2 and H2O abiotically back to carbohydrate, and process any wastes back to carbohydrate as well, then feed them along with reduced nitrogen and minerals to the yeast.

It is possible to genetically engineer yeast to make lots of different flavors, even with current technology.

https://courses.lumenlearning.com/odessa-readinganthology-1/chapter/audio-genetically-engineered-yeast-is-the-future-of-flavor-by-gastropod/

> Until recently, the natural flavors that Hagen uses would, for the
>   most part, have been extracted from a plant; a handful of rarer
>   ingredients, more often used in perfumery, would have come from animal
>   sources. Today, advances in genetic engineering, combined with the
>   growing consumer demand for natural flavors, are creating an
>   intriguing new option for the world’s flavorists. In the past, the
>   mention of “edible yeast” in the FDA definition of natural flavors
>   typically referred to savory yeast extracts; now, designer yeasts are
>   beginning to pump out vanilla, saffron, and even grapefruit flavors.

It is easy to keep a lot of different engineered strains of yeast frozen, then grow them up for different food flavors.

I propose that every different animal on earth will have corresponding yeasts, so your ship goers can go on a culinary virtual tour of the earth, eating their virtual way through the entire animal (including extinct animals) and vegetable / fungus kingdoms without risk of dying from food poisoning or kuru.  Not all foods will be available at the same time and so shipgoers can mark the days until passenger pigeon and Yohimbe vine are on the menu.  Yeast can also be engineered to make therapeutic and recreational drugs and the latter will be routinely used before embarking on aforementioned virtual eating tour of the world.

Answer (score 2):

Prepare to be disgusted:

## Waste, mostly.

The way generation ships work is that they are standalone ecosystems entirely supporting themselves. This means there can be no waste of any kind. Excrement like faeces and urine would need to be reused after filtering, or as fertiliser. Even things like sweat would need to be caught and recycled. Basically everything a human consumes (and expels) would need to be reused at some point, as there are simply not enough resources to just throw anything out.

How this looks in practise would most likely be the same as on earth, a combination of farming and livestock to recycle any waste. However it would need to be tailored with extreme precision, to make the recycling process as efficient as possible without the loss of any necessary nutrients. Mostly food would be boring and people would eat the same dishes and strict diets as they are designed to be the most efficient transfer of nutrients. The amount of ingredients available would be severely restricted.

Comment: Well we need to try this on Earth first. We know the risks of viruses occurring and in such an environment would likely be fatal. I do wonder if some of our waste would be ejected into Space e.g. dead/cremated bodies to prevent what the equivalent might be of CJD. Depletion of course would then be occurring.